# Detect horizontal blank lines in .pdf form image with OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have `.pdf` files that have been converted to `.jpg` images for this project. My goal is to identify the blanks (e.g ____________) that you would generally find in a `.pdf` form that indicate a space for the user to sign of fill out some kind of information. I have been using edge detection with the `cv2.Canny()` and `cv2.HoughlinesP()` functions.

This works fairly well, but there are quite a few false positives that come about from seemingly nowhere. When I look at the 'edges' file it shows a bunch of noise around the other words. I'm uncertain where this noise comes from.

Should I continue to tweak the parameters, or is there a better method to find the location of these blanks?

Comment: Are you trying to find the blank entries to eventually fill them in, or for other purposes? You can use `pdfrw` to fill in blank PDF forms. Check out [this](https://bostata.com/how-to-populate-fillable-pdfs-with-python/) blog post if relevant.

Comment: Currently, the pdf is not fillable. It is just the text. I am trying to identify the areas that should be fillable and then create a docusign export to generate the fillable part.

Comment: Post an example to some free hosting service and put the URL here. You could search for certain minimum length horizontal lines using morphology.

Comment: One method would be to use a special horizontal kernel and morphological transformations to isolate the lines. Adding an input and expected output image would be helpful

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]
[image]

Assuming that you're trying to find horizontal lines on a `.pdf` form, here's a simple approach:

- Convert image to grayscale and adaptive threshold image
- Construct special kernel to detect only horizontal lines
- Perform morphological transformations
- Find contours and draw onto image

---

Using this example image

[image]

Convert to grayscale and adaptive threshold to obtain a binary image

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

[image]

Then we create a kernel with `cv2.getStructuringElement()` and perform morphological transformations to isolate horizontal lines

```
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (15,1))
detected_lines = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
```

[image]

From here we can use `cv2.HoughLinesP()` to detect lines but since we have already preprocessed the image and isolated the horizontal lines, we can just find contours and draw the result

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(detected_lines, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 3)
```

[image]

Full code

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('2.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (15,1))
detected_lines = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)

cnts = cv2.findContours(detected_lines, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 3)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('detected_lines', detected_lines)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: However, now I'm coming across the issue of false positives for words that are underlined in the text. Any idea how to solve for this?

Comment: You can play with the `cv2.getStructuringElement()` kernel size so changing `(15,1)` to say `(11,1)` will "loosen" the filter. Also changing the number of iterations in `cv2.morphologyEx()` may help

Comment: @nathancy - Thanks for the great solution. However, I am using PyPDF2 and stuck with the ability to read the pages from the PDF as images. Can you help on that? Maybe add code to the answer above?? TNX!

Comment: I would suggest adding ```cv2.destroyAllWindows()``` at the end of the code. It will stop it crashing.