# Locating X&Y of horizontal lines in PDF or JPG

Tags: python, opencv, pypdf

I am trying to locate the X&Y of all horizontal lines in a PDF document.
I was using the code here:
[code to detect horizontal lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57260893/detect-horizontal-blank-lines-in-pdf-form-image-with-opencv)

This code marks the horizontal lines verywell but I am not able to extract their coordinates in the document.

This is my code:

```
def DetectLine(pageNum):
    # Convert to grayscale and adaptive threshold to obtain a binary image
    img = cv2.imread(outpath + 'page_' + str(pageNum) + '.jpg')
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    # Then we create a kernel and perform morphological transformations to isolate horizontal lines
    horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (15,1))
    detected_lines = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
    # detect lines find contours and draw the result
    cnts = cv2.findContours(detected_lines, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    for c in cnts:
        cv2.drawContours(img, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 3)
    cv2.imshow('image_' + str(pageNum), img)
```

This function gets the pagenumber and reads a pre-prepared JPG of the specific page.

How can I return the Xs & Ys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If only need the points:**
you can extract it with:

Point 1: `c[0][0]` or `cnts[num]c[0][0]`

Point 2: `c[1][0]` or `cnts[num]c[1][0]`

where num is the index of the contour

**Middle point**
The solution will be:

```
(cnts[0][1][0][0]+cnts[0][0][0][0])//2,cnts[0][0][0][1]
```

Since each line or countour for get has two points, you can calculate the middle point with the average formula.
e.g:
x1=10 and x2=90, the middle point then is (10+90)/2

Here is the complete code:

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('2.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (15,1))
detected_lines = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel,     iterations=2)

cnts = cv2.findContours(detected_lines, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,     cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

for c in cnts:
    x,y=(c[1][0][0]+c[0][0][0])//2,c[0][0][1]
    print(f'The middle point is: x: {x}, y: {y}')
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 3)
    cv2.circle(image, (x,y), radius=5, color=(0, 0, 255), thickness=-1)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('detected_lines', detected_lines)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

The result image is the following:
[image: Result image]

Comment: Thanks for that!! Howeer, now I have a different problem. The purpose of finding the horizontal lines was to get the Xs & Ys and manipulate a PDF file via PyPDF2 library. BUT the Xs & Ys I get from the CV2 does not match the location if I use them on the PDF with the PyPDF... Any idea?

Comment: X's and Y's gotten by openCV doesn't match which one? What points are you looking for?

Comment: I am using the x,y to add text on a PDF (where the images orignated from) using PyPDF2. But the location I get is wrong

Comment: you could get use of it, if you want to put text above the line, you could add 10 or 15 pixels to the y coordinate. Then put the text in (x,y-15)